# How to insert an additional varray record in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create type recordObj as object(
rID varchar(5),
rName varchar(5));

create type recordsArr as varray(2) of recordObj;

create table RecordsTable(
ID varchar(3),
records recordsArr);

insert into RecordsTable values ('RE1', recordsArr(recordObj('RE-12','CONF')));
```

After successfully inserting this row, I want to add an additional record into the 'recordsArr' varray where RecordsTable ID is also 'RE1', since varray is of size 2, but I don't want to do it in the query I have just written. If I run this query again, but with two 'recordObj' inserts, it just duplicates the data and create a new row. I want add a new varray record but in the existing record where ID is 'RE1'. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it via PL/SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_records recordsArr;
BEGIN
  SELECT records
  INTO   p_records
  FROM   recordsTable
  WHERE  id = 'RE1'
  FOR UPDATE;
  
  p_records.EXTEND;
  p_records(2) := recordObj( 'RE-13', 'ABC' );

  UPDATE RecordsTable
  SET records = p_records
  WHERE id = 'RE1';
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT id,
       r.*
FROM   recordsTable rt
       CROSS JOIN TABLE( rt.records ) r;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | RID | RNAME |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | RE1 | RE-12 | CONF |
> | RE1 | RE-13 | ABC |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2690c2209ef6f2421595acc55637dce3)*

---

If, instead, you created the data-type as a collection using:

```sql
create type recordObj as object(
  rID varchar(5),
  rName varchar(5)
);

create type recordsArr as table of recordObj;           -- TABLE not VARRAY(2)

create table RecordsTable(
  ID varchar(3),
  records recordsArr
) NESTED TABLE records STORE AS recordstable__records;  -- Add storage for the collection

insert into RecordsTable values ('RE1', recordsArr(recordObj('RE-12','CONF')));
```

Then you could use:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE( SELECT records FROM RecordsTable WHERE id = 'RE1' )
VALUES ( 'RE-14', 'DEF' );
```

But, that will not work for a `VARRAY`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f42a62c6110018ae8ef035fb495730d)*